# Find out how many tickets were open each day historically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like the below

```
 ID   | CreatedDate   |  CloseDate
271   | 01-Jan-2018   |  02-Jan-2018
278   | 03-Jan-2018   |  05-Jan-2018
333   | 03-Jan-2018   |     NULL
```

I have been tasked to find out for each day in a month, how many tickets remained open going into the next day.  A ticket would be classed as remaining open if the CloseDate was not on the same date as the created date, or the CloseDate is NULL.

My ideal output from the above would look like this

```
Day          | Tickets Remaining
01-Jan-2018  |        1
02-Jan-2018  |        0
03-Jan-2018  |        2
04-Jan-2018  |        2
05-Jan-2018  |        1
```

Does this make sense? Using SQL Server 2016..

Comment: *"**I** have been tasked to find out for each day in a month"* *You* have been asked; we haven't been. What have *you* tried, why didn't it work? Please don't request us to do your work for you.

Comment: Honestly, I haven't an idea where to start with it. I tried a case statement but I just couldn't get my head around what to do with it. I am not expecting the full piece of work to be done for me, just some direction as I am still learning..

Comment: At least show us that attempt then. The only question you've asked above is *"Does this make sense?"* which isn't a programming question. Provide us with the problem you have with your SQL, and explain why it's not giving the results your after.

Comment: The first step would be to generate all dates between jan month. Then peform a left join with the table you got and then count the records where the date from the first block matches within the boundary of the table open and close dates

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a number/tally table handy, you can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, createddate as dte, coalesce(closeddate, convert(date, getdate())) as closeddate
      from t
      union all
      select id, dateadd(day, 1, dte), closeddate
      from cte
      where dte < closeddate
     )
select dte, count(*)
from cte
group by dte;
```

Note:  If any of the timespans can exceed 100 days, then you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)`.

If there are only a handful of dates, you can use a derived table and `left join`:

```
select v.dte, count(t.id)
from (values (convert(date, '2018-01-01')),
             (convert(date, '2018-01-02')),
             (convert(date, '2018-01-03')),
             (convert(date, '2018-01-04')),
             (convert(date, '2018-01-05')),
     ) v(dte) left join
     t
     on v.dte >= t.createddate and
        (v.dte <= t.closeddate or t.closeddate is null)
group by v.dte
order by v.dte;
```